# Power M Custom Pivot in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, powerquery

I have a Power Query in Excel that looks something like this:

Name | Tips
Anne | 3.00
Anne | 2.00
Mary | 4.00
Mary | 2.50
Jane | 6.00
Jane | 3.30

This is the Power M code I am using:

```
#"Table Pivot" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", {"Tips"},"Tips","Tips", List.Sum)
```

Right now I am getting this:

Name | Tips
Anne | null
Mary | null
Jane | null

This is what I want to see:

Name | Tips
Anne | 5.00
Mary | 6.50
Jane | 9.30

How can I make this happen in Power M?  Any help is appreciated, I am still pretty new to Power M.  I think there is something I am not understand or that I am missing. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

In Power Query (a.k.a. M), Table.Pivot is used to pivot a column, i.e. transpose values to columns (1 column for each of the text values in the column you are pivoting), e.g.if you want a column for each name.

What you are looking for is Group By, as illustrated in the picture below, with the generated code displayed in the formula bar:

[image: Group By]